# How to get the first variation of a complex lagrangian?

Tags: complex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

How do I get the first variation for this:
$$ \int_C L\left(z,\phi,\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}z}\right)\mathrm{d}z$$
where:
$$z=x+iy,$$
$$\mathrm{d}z=\mathrm{d}x+i\mathrm{d}y,$$
$$\phi=f(x,y)+ig(x,y).$$
The integral is a complex line integral and $\phi$ is an analytical function.
I'm not sure whether the process is identical to that of real analysis. Is it even possible to get such a variation? Does it even make any sense?